# Whats the best way to use bootstrap with Piranha CMS

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, content-management-system, piranha-cms

I would like to use a bootstrap theme and use **PiranhaCMS** to allow the user to create and edit pages.  How can I provide editor templates to allow the user to create pages and ensure that the proper bootstrap classes are used?

The users that will be creating pages are not going to understand basic HTML so I am limited to what they can do within the editor.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Tiny MCE editors homepage. You can easily add custom stylesheets & classes to the wysiwyg editor that your clients can choose from without understanding HTML!